# raw_rnn vs scan in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to understand which one is best for my project. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using [`raw_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/raw_rnn) over [`scan`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan) when writing a recurrent neural network?

Is `raw_rnn` more general? If so, what is an example of something that `raw_rnn` can do that `scan` cannot?